# Secure string.Format object C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, security

I am working in C# for the first time in awhile, I have a line of code like this.

```
SQL = string.Format("PageName = '{0}'", bp.CommandArgument);
```

I need to know how to secure the object "bp.CommandArgument" from any SQL Injection. Thank you.

Comment: Do not use string formatting/concatenation to create SQL queries in first place, Use [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use sql parameters?

```
string commandTxt = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE PageName=@PageName";
var command = new SqlCommand(commandTxt, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@PageName", bp.CommandArgument);
```

I assume that `connection` is the `SqlConnection` object you have declared.